# Daisy Chaining Mixers

Tags: pa

I have two mixers, yamaha mg12xu and stage pas powered mixer. I would like to connect these two together so that as I have a problem with distance but wiuld not like to buy cables.

Can I connect everything to mg12xu and from there, output to stagepas mixer? Then from there I'd connect it to the speakers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plug the mixer straight into the powered mixer, using one channel (or two if stereo). Plug whatever you need into the mixer, which I guess is a powered mixer amp., leaving the eq. flat on the powered mixer. It'll all work fine, I've used set-ups like this for years.

Comment: Give it a bit longer - other, better answers may be forthcoming.